# What is an icon or symbol that denotes 'automatic'?

Tags: icons, symbols

What is an icon or symbol that denotes 'automatic' ?

More details:
Working on an application where there will be a list of bills, some with an actionable button inline that says 'Pay', and others are not actionable as they automatically are billed.

My options:
Disabled / grey type button that is labled 'Automatic'
Just a label that states 'Automatic'
Or an icon / symbol that denotes 'Automatic'

I will be testing all the above options, however I am stumped as to what type of symbol or icon could represent something that is going to be actioned automatically. Suggestions to this would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circular arrow - the same icon that most web browsers use to indicate Refresh. You'll also see this icon used on Calendars to indicate a recurring event and some online banks will use this icon to indicate a recurring payment/bank transfer.

[image]

from: http://www.defaulticon.com

Comment: My only concern is that these items may not be recurring, but one off scheduled bills. I could use the rotating arrows I guess for the recurring items, and something else for the one off scheduled, but maybe that is over complicating it?

Comment: I would suggest rotating circular arrows for recurring events and a simple (low-fi) analog clock face to indicate an automated scheduled event.  The following image is used as a Scheduled Recording icon for a TV Tuner's PVR and the clock face icon is a perfect representation of what I am talking about: http://www.pcmeal.com/ebay/Leadtek/WinFastDTV2000DS/icon_scheduled_recording.jpg

Comment: Facing the same issue today. I'm thinking about overlaying a play-triangle for automatic enabled and overlaying the two vertical pause-lines for disabled. In some case a circular overlay would also be good with a "1" as an overlay for manual action.